# Why is the Visual Studio Code native-mode menu dropdown white, even though I have dark mode activated in my desktop's settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why is the `Visual Studio Code` native-mode menu `dropdown white`, even though I have dark mode activated and I use `Fedora Linux` and the dark mode is activated in `Fedora`, yet it is white? What is the solution as shown in the picture?

[image]

I don't try anything because I can't know the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why the native title bar mode is showing up for you with light mode colouring. Supposedly, you can switch to dark mode on the GNOME desktop environment with the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Adwaita-dark
```

(or whatever other dark mode theme is available on your machine)

But if that doesn't work, you can get colouring consistent with your selected colour theme in VS Code by putting this in your settings.json:

```json
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
```

The description for that setting:

> Adjust the appearance of the window title bar. On Linux and Windows, this setting also affects the application and context menu appearances. Changes require a full restart to apply.

Comment: it changed the appearance so menus are under the ||| (horizontal) button but its now like the latest appearance in windows. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Dalton see also the `window.menuBarVisibility` visibility for that behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Open Settings and search for Title Bar Style. Changing that option to custom could possibly fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you for trying it out and working with me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Behold this is what worked for me in arch with gnome

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this in Fedora workstation 38 by following steps:

1. Install gnome-tweaks, if you have not already installed.

```
    sudo dnf install gnome-tweaks
```

2. Launch gnome-tweaks
3. Go to,  Appearance -> Themes -> Legacy Application (option) -> Select Dark theme.

That's it. Now it will look normal

Comment: This fixed it instantly, thanks! Even Rhythmbox now has a dark-theme (it previously stuck in light-theme in dark mode).

Comment: Is there a change in gnome-tweaks for fedora 39? I can't seem to find `Themes` anywhere. There is though Legacy Applications under style but it doesn't have Dark theme option. Can you maybe help cuz I'm stuck with white dialog boxes even with custom option selected for both `Dialog Style` and `Title Bar Style`